# how can I set Impressions Goal in the new admob?

Tags: admob

Can I set how many impressions I need to promote on my apps in the new admob as old one ??
I can't find it!!

There is no option to set goal impressions ?

is only time campaigns

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about AdMob, belongs to http://webmaster.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This feature was just recently launched in the new AdMob UI. You should see an option when editing your mediation settings.